# MySQL Workbench Error 1064

Tags: mysql, workbench

everyone! I'm newbie to MySQL. I've created a new model using Workbench tools(I mean, that I haven't written any string of code by myself).
When trying to forward engineer it I get:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 8
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `university`.`CITY`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `university`.`CITY` (
      `ID_CITY` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `CNAME` TEXT(15) NULL COMMENT '',
      `POPULATION` INT NULL COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CITY`)  COMMENT '')
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

 Fetching back view definitions in final form.
 Nothing to fetch
```

Moreover, when trying to forward engineer default Workbench model "sakila_full" i get the same thing:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT '',
INDEX `idx_actor_last_name` (`last_name` ASC)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE ' at line 9
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `sakila`.`actor`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`actor` (
      `actor_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
      `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`)  COMMENT '',
      INDEX `idx_actor_last_name` (`last_name` ASC)  COMMENT '')
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

 SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

 Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Could not get definition for sakila.customer_list from server
Could not get definition for sakila.film_list from server
Could not get definition for sakila.nicer_but_slower_film_list from server
Could not get definition for sakila.staff_list from server
Could not get definition for sakila.sales_by_store from server
Could not get definition for sakila.sales_by_film_category from server
Could not get definition for sakila.actor_info from server
7 views were read back.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: error could also come around when u have defined a SET/ENUM and havent populated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've taken the `COMMENT` strings a little too far. According to [the MySQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), a `COMMENT` attribute is only permitted on a column definition. That means it's invalid on the `INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` definitions you have listed near the end of your `CREATE` statements.

The `COMMENT ''` aren't necessary and can be omitted entirely, especially since you are leaving them blank. Otherwise, they would be used for a little bit of extra human-readable metadata on your column definitions.

To get this working with what you have, remove the `COMMENT` attributes from your index and primary key definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `university`.`CITY` (
  `ID_CITY` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `CNAME` TEXT(15) NULL COMMENT '',
  `POPULATION` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  -- No COMMENT on PK
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CITY`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`actor` (
  `actor_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  -- No COMMENT on PK or INDEX
  PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
  INDEX `idx_actor_last_name` (`last_name` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Or the whole thing without *any* blank `COMMENT`s:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `university`.`CITY` (
  `ID_CITY` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'A comment that is not blank!',
  `CNAME` TEXT(15) NULL,
  `POPULATION` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CITY`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

(Same for the other table)

MySQL is generally quite good at pointing you directly to the source of your syntax error with the error message:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT ''),

With the exception of errors occurring at the end of the statement, which get a little ambiguous, the *right syntax to use near* will show you exactly what's amiss. In the above case, the `COMMENT '')` should direct you to the only  `COMMENT` attribute followed by a `)`, which was the one at `PRIMARY KEY`.  From there, check the manual (linked above) for legal syntax in each segment of your statement.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this :)

Comment: @Kleeo Great, let us know if you encounter any issues, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you have not already.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the BIG probleme is that Mysql Workbench adds itself indexes comments that generate an error, when using "Forward Engineer" or "Synchronize Model"

This problem did not exist when I was using version 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "VISIBLE" and "INVISIBLE" words from all INDEX